# Changing line spacing within paragraphs

Tags: spacing

I want to change the separation between lines in paragraphs by factor of `1.3`.  How does one do that ?

Had a go at using

```
\setstretch{1.618}
```

and

```
\setstretch{baselinestretch 1.3}
```

Here is my document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \title{AGAMA}
  \author{Pengo}
  \date{\today}

  \maketitle
  \tableofcontents
\end{titlepage}

\setstretch{1.618}
\setstretch{baselinestretch 1.3}

\chapter{Introduction}
This chapter's content...

\end{document}
```

But latex complains with

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.81 \setstretch
                {1.618}

! Undefined control sequence.
l.82 \setstretch
                {baselinestretch 1.3}
```

Comment: "But latex complains about them." Please be a bit more specific. `\setstretch` is a macro provided by the [setspace](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/setspace) package.  The macro takes a single positive number as its argument.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: ... please also include which error message you get instead of just saying "latex complains about them"

Comment: If you can put the text with the modified `\baselineskip` into a `\vbox` etc, no problem.  If you increase the font size or add lots of larger struts, the spacing will equal the strut size plus `\lineskip`.

Comment: Another possibility in addition to the answer by @Celdor:  After a blank line, enter `\begingroup \setstretch{<factor>}`.  Then your paragraph text.  At the end, `\par \endgroup` and finish up with another blank line.  The explicit grouping isolates the changed baselines, and the `\par` is necessary to "freeze" the reset.  Requires the `setspace` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to help if you don't provide details of your problem. Also, it depends on what you want to achieve. This is not a trivial problem and you are advised to gather more info about it. Here is a good document on Overleaf: [How to change paragraph spacing in LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_change_paragraph_spacing_in_LaTeX).

Anyway, you probably should load [setspace](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package and use this macro

```
\setstretch{<factor>}
```

Here the `<factor>` is related to `1.2`, a **ratio** of `\baselineskip` and font size. By default, this is `12pt/10pt = 1.2`. `\setstretch` alters this number by the `<factor>`, that is a new baseline stretch becomes `1.2 x <factor>`.

Having said that, if you just want to increase paragraph spacing exactly by `1.3`, simply use `\setstretch{1.3}`; you will gain a slightly larger spacing compared to one-half spacing because the new **ratio** becomes `1.56`.

On the other hand, you need to work out the `<factor>` if you want to gain desired *1.3-spacing*. Simply divide the *spacing* by the **ratio** and use such a number in `\setstretch`. For instance, the new baseline stretch in your case becomes `1.3/1.2 = 1.083`. One important note: the **ratio** might differ between documents as well as font sizes (see [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_change_paragraph_spacing_in_LaTeX)).

For comparison, the following are common factors: for one-half spacing -> `factor = 1.5/1.2 = 1.25` and for double spacing -> `factor = 2/1.2 = 1.67`. In the latter cases though, one is advised to use `\onehalfspacing` or `\doublespacing` instead.

Here's an example. Note, apart from the macro `\setstretch`, you can also use environments

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% \setstretch{1.3}%


\begin{document}
Standard spacing: \kant[1]

\bigskip

\begin{setstretch}{1.083}
  \kant[2]
\end{setstretch}

\bigskip

\begin{setstretch}{1.3}
  \kant[3]
\end{setstretch}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I show that I am making a computation for factor ? Perhaps using a formula, then setting the correct factor value as you described?

Comment: Let's say, the X-spacing is what you want to achieve. Here, 1.5- and 2-spacing is equivalent to one-half and double spacing, respectively. Then, you divide `X` by `1.2` (valid for standard documents) and this number is your `factor` in `\setstretch{factor}` macro. Hence, in your case, the factor for 1.3-spacing becomes `1.083`.